# How do I get the text from an entry box in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried creating a login system. it gives me a: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

here is the code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

window = tkinter.Tk()

def addUsernm():
    a = usernl.get("1.0", 'end-1c')
    print(a)

usernames = []
passwords = []

usernl = tkinter.Entry(window).pack()
passwrdnl = tkinter.Entry(window).pack()



submitbtn = tkinter.Button(window,text="submit",command=addUsernm).pack()

window.mainloop()
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, you're confusing the `Text` widget `get` method, with the `Entry` widget `get` method, and they aren't the same method. Also you can't use `pack` on the same line as widget or the variable won't be saving anything. This is the solution that worked for me:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Button

window = Tk()
window.state("zoomed")

def add():
    a = user.get()
    b = password.get()
    print(a, b)


user = Entry(window)
user.pack()
password = Entry(window)
password.pack()

Button(window, text="submit", command=add).pack()

window.mainloop()
```